# Check if a substring is contained in a string in Javascript (The Opposite Way)

Tags: javascript, string

I'm **not** asking for substr, indexOf, includes, substring functions; it's the opposite of that like `"apple".isIncludedIn("apple tree")`

Is there a function that checks the other way around the usual way of checking? If a substring is contained in a string in javascript where the substring is the object of action.

Because I want to be able to safely check without the null exception issue for the case that I know the substring but the string to check on is a variable, e.g.

```
let arr = [null, "apple tree"]
let str = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
if ("apple".isIncludedIn(str)) {
  console.log("It is!");
}
```

Because `str.includes("apple")` can result to `Cannot read property 'includes' of null`

[Additional Note]

I'm aware that I can do `(str && str.includes())` or `((str || '').includes())` but these seem "hacky" to me (personal opinion).

Comment: `const f = any => typeof any === 'string' ? any.includes('apple') : false;`

Answer (score 1):

Just reverse the argument and the string being called on. To achieve

```
"apple".isIncludedIn("apple tree")
```

do

```
"apple tree".includes("apple")
```

To also permit `nulls` without throwing, use optional chaining if you want to be concise.

```js
let arr = [null, "apple tree"]
let str = arr[Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length)];
if (str?.includes("apple")) {
  console.log("It is!");
} else {
  console.log("It's not");
}
```

For obsolete browsers that don't understand optional chaining, just like all uses of modern syntax, use [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) to transpile your code down to ES6 or ES5 for production automatically.

Comment: I like this answer, but be forewarned that while [browser support for the optional chaining operator (`?.`)](https://caniuse.com/?search=optional%20chaining).is almost all the way there, it isn't quite perfect.

Comment: I didn't know about the question mark notation. Thanks! The other options seem "hacky" to me, like `str && str.includes()` or `(str || '').includes()` .

Answer (score 0):

Using `||` operator will solve your issue.

```js
(str || '').includes("apple")
```

If `str` is `null`, it checks with `''` so returns false

If `str` is present, it returns if string contains substring